# Office.Interop.Word and Lists with SubLevels

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, office-interop

I've been scouring the interwebs for documentation leading me to be able to create lists.  In doing so, I've not really been able to find any documentation that will allow me to create `lists within lists.

I've tried using the built-in macro recorder, but for whatever reason, it behaves differently when recording vs. when not recording (e.g. when I create a list item, and hit enter + tab, it doesn't create a sub list).

I've found "The Wordmeister's" MSDN post which helped me get to making a list, but lists within lists doesn't work so well for me.

```
            Word.Paragraph p2 = doc.Paragraphs.Add();
            Word.Range p2rng = p2.Range;
            object oTrue = true;
            object oFalse = false;
            object oListName = "TreeList";

            Word.ListTemplate lstTemp = doc.ListTemplates.Add(ref oTrue, ref oListName);
            int l;

            p2rng.ParagraphFormat.TabIndent(1);
            p2rng.Text = "Rates:\r\nLevel 1\rLevel 1.1\rLevel 1.2\rLevel 2\rLevel 2.1\rLevel 2.1.1";

            l = 1;
            lstTemp.ListLevels[l].NumberFormat = "%" + l.ToString() + ".";
            lstTemp.ListLevels[l].NumberStyle = Word.WdListNumberStyle.wdListNumberStyleArabic;
            lstTemp.ListLevels[l].NumberPosition = wordApp.CentimetersToPoints(0.5f * (l - 1));
            lstTemp.ListLevels[l].TextPosition = wordApp.CentimetersToPoints(0.5f * l);
            l = 2;
            lstTemp.ListLevels[l].NumberFormat = "%" + (l - 1).ToString() + ".%" + l.ToString() + ".";
            lstTemp.ListLevels[l].NumberStyle = Word.WdListNumberStyle.wdListNumberStyleArabic;
            lstTemp.ListLevels[l].NumberPosition = wordApp.CentimetersToPoints(0.5f * (l - 1));
            lstTemp.ListLevels[l].TextPosition = wordApp.CentimetersToPoints(0.5f * l);
            l = 3;
            lstTemp.ListLevels[l].NumberFormat = "%" + (l - 2).ToString() + "%" + (l - 1).ToString() + ".%" + l.ToString() + ".";
            lstTemp.ListLevels[l].NumberStyle = Word.WdListNumberStyle.wdListNumberStyleArabic;
            lstTemp.ListLevels[l].NumberPosition = wordApp.CentimetersToPoints(0.5f * (l - 1));
            lstTemp.ListLevels[l].TextPosition = wordApp.CentimetersToPoints(0.5f * l);
            object oListApplyTo = Word.WdListApplyTo.wdListApplyToWholeList;
            object oListBehavior = Word.WdDefaultListBehavior.wdWord10ListBehavior;

            p2rng.ListFormat.ApplyListTemplate(lstTemp, ref oFalse, ref oListApplyTo, ref oListBehavior);
```

All credit to Cindy Meister for this code, it is only slightly modified to work for my use case.

The above results in the following:

[image]

Basically, how do you create multi level lists (like the following image) with lists within lists?

[image]

Comment: @Jaberwocky the Interop API is the same as that used by VBA. You can record a macro while creating a nested list and convert the VBA code to C#. *You most definitedly don't need to hand-code numbers and bullets* though. Word itself provides that for lists. You don't need (actually shouldn't) to use `\r\n` to generate lines in a paragraph. None of those characters will result in the soft-newline you want.

Comment: @Jaberwocky as for the macro recorder not working the same, it's because what you do is *not* what you do - when you click `tab` you *don'* create a second level list, you insert a Tab. Word can "autocorrect" that and apply a `List 2` style instead of adding a tab to the list. If you simply applied the correct style to the second list item, you'd see that the macro recorder's code and your own actions would match

Comment: @Jaberwocky you should probably learn how Word works first, how formatting, lists, numbering etc work. Just like HTML, you can try to align and format a page with tabs, spaces and wonder why it doesn't work. Or you can read about divs, css etc and generate a nicely formatted page.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really possible to create a "list within a list" in Word.

What you can do is put static text in the list level, in front of the dynamic number. This is the same idea as using "Chapter" or "Section" in front of the level's number, except in this case it should be a bullet symbol.

The place to define this, based on the code sample in the question, is:

```
lstTemp.ListLevels[l].NumberFormat = "%" + l.ToString() + ".";
```

As part of the `NumberFormat` string, in other words. For symobls this will require a conversion from unicode hex or decimal to the `String` data type. For example, for a solid, round bullet and an outline, round bullet for levels 1 and 2, respectively (hard-coding the list level for purposes of clarity):

```
char Symbol1 = (char)9679;
char Symbol2 = (char)9675;
lstTemp.ListLevels[1].NumberFormat = Symbol1.ToString() + "\t%" + l.ToString() + ".";
lstTemp.ListLevels[2].NumberFormat = Symbol2.ToString() + "\t%" + 2.ToString() + ".";
```

Answer (score -1):

Lets try providing an answer that doesn't get deleted.

The updated list within lists example provided by @Jaberwocky can be achieved using the technique I explained in a previous post.

[MS-Word: Cross reference to custom reference type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52704878/ms-word-cross-reference-to-custom-reference-type/52737543#52737543)

To apply the above to the specific instance required by @Jaberwock we need to amend the number formats of the list templates to which styles are linked.  I'll use Word to set up the styles and required multilevel list and then include a short VBA macro which shows how to amend the list number format.

In line with the link above we first need to create our styles.  The emulate the list within list example above we need to define two styles.  I've defined 'ListWithinList 1' and 'ListWithinList 2'.

The key settings for these two styles are to set the outline level as 1 and 2 respectively, and to set appropriate tab stops. I've used tabs at 1,2,3 and 4 cm.  Add some text to a word document and apply the styles.  I've included the navigation pane in the picture below so that we can see the indentation due to the outline level of the styles

[image]

The next step is to define the multilevel list and link each level to the relevant style

Settings for outline level 1

[image]

settings for outline level 2

[image]

Our text now looks like this

[image]

I've used Word up to this point to avoid the tediousness of setting up styles and list templates programatically.

Let's now modify the format of the list numbering using a snippet of VBA.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub AddTextToListNumber()

Dim my_prefix(1 To 2)                   As String
Dim my_index                            As Long

    my_prefix(1) = ChrW(&H25AA) & vbTab ' small black square
    my_prefix(2) = ChrW(&H25AB) & vbTab ' small white square

    For my_index = 1 To 2

        With ActiveDocument.Styles("ListWithinList " & CStr(my_index)).ListTemplate.ListLevels(my_index)
            .numberformat = my_prefix(my_index) & .numberformat
        End With
    Next

End Sub
```

If we run the code above then the text in our document becomes

[image]

Which looks a bit ugly because of the 1cm tab stops.

If there is anything that isn't clear above please add a comment and if possible I'll update the answer.

NOTE:  We didn't need the VBA code to complete setting up the list formats as we could have used appropriate Alt+XXXX keyboard sequences to insert the characters in the number format box of the multilevel list dialog box.

Comment: While the OP definitely needs some training in Word, this answer doesn't provide any relevant *code*. It doesn't contain anything that can be used to generate nested lists with interop. In the end, the OP will still have to use the macro recorder to create the appropriate calls

Comment: The answer provides exactly the solution the OP needs. Interop is just a red herring because as far as I know there is no macro recorder for interop. Before you can write any coded solution you need to understand how to create and manipulate word lists. The short vba snippet provides code that is easy to experiment with and which shows the OP exactly how to modify the interior  code he presented.

Comment: SO is a Q&A site about programming. This is an end user tutorial - that's only the expected answer. It contains no code, it can't be used by anyone else that may know how to create nested lists in Word but not how to do so programmatically

Comment: In fact, I see you were already given that advice. Check the *accepted* answer to the question you linked to. That's what's expected here

Comment: I thought stackoverflow was about helping people solve Thier problems. Not providing a code writing service.

Comment: Those two answers do neither. If you wanted to *help* you'd explain that word has paragraphs and ranges, the paragraphs have styles, and the OP needs to apply the proper style to each. That's what nafarkash did in the accepted answer. This answer doesn't do that. *Creating* those paragraphs in code isn't that obvious either, even when you use the macro recorder

Comment: 'If you wanted to help you'd explain that word has paragraphs and ranges, the paragraphs have styles, and the OP needs to apply the proper style to each. '   
And that isn't a tutorial.'  You should note that my final comment was to invite the OP to comment on anything that he didn't understand and I would update the answer.  If you wanted to be helpful rather than inappropriately criticizing my contribution you could edit my answer to provide the information you think is missing.

Comment: Actually, I agree with @PanagiotisKanavos. If the "answer" to a question is: you first need to learn this in the UI, then use the macro recorder - then it should be a comment to the question with a link to Super User if more assistance is needed to learn how to use the functionality in the UI. This kind of answer belongs on Super User, not on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Sigh.  I included the information on how I set up the styles and the multilevel list so that the OP would be able to replicate what I had done and hence the VBA snippet I provided would work as required.  The critical bit is the VBA code which shows how you can find and modify the number format string of the list template which is linked to the style.  I could have added lots of code that defined the styles and defined the list template but this is actually a separate issue, if it needs addressing at all.

Comment: My two cents here.  You're right.  SO is not a code writing service.  It is a resource to ask others to help you attain the knowledge you need to accomplish whatever task you're stuck on.  I was not asking for anyone to write the code for me.  Never even insinuated it.  I asked, given the information I already provided and researched, what I needed to move forward on creating multi-level lists in a programmatically generated word document.  Cindy's answers never do the job for me, but almost always guide me in the right direction to finding the solution for myself.  That's my expectation.